# Django - Take username of logged user as default value to another model

Tags: django

I have the model "Account" below:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    email=models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username=models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    data_inscricao=models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Data de Inscrição', auto_now_add=True)
    ultimo_login=models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='ùltimo Login', auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

and this other "PersonalData"...

```
class PersonalData(models.Model):
    id_user=models.OneToOneField(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nome_completo=models.CharField(max_length=56, unique=True, null=True)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=60, verbose_name="Email", unique=True, null=True)
    cpf=models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=True, null=True, verbose_name="CPF")
    rg=models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True, null=True, verbose_name="RG")
    idade=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    data_nascimento=models.DateField(verbose_name="Data de Nascimento", null=True)
    genero=models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=GENERO, null=True)
    estado_civil=models.CharField(max_length=13, null=True, choices=ESTADO_CIVIL, verbose_name="Estado Civil")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome_completo
```

views.py

```py
def cadastro_curriculo(request):
    form = InsereDadosPessoais(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect("vagas")
    return render(request, "personal/curriculo.html", {'form': form,})
```

forms.py

```py
class InsereDadosPessoais(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PersonalData
        fields = '__all__'
```

I'ld like PersonalData.id_user use by default the Account.username of the loged user and I don't know how do that.

Just to exemplify, In Django Admin, my PersonalData model allows me to choose the user, but I want it to happen automatically and not manually.

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: No, actually this field is just to identify witch user is linked with the PersonalData, but i wanted this happen automatically when the user is loged.

Comment: Apparently you created a view and form so the user can create/update `PersonalData`. That's where you can make the link to the currently logged in user. So please show us your view.

Comment: Youre right, add to the question

Comment: @A.Raouf's answer will give you the correct direction, even though he assumed this was for admin.py. Don't add `user` to your form and assign it manually under `form.is_valid()`. See the example on `commit=False` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at `admin.py` add the admin class as per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects)
assign `exclude` as per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude)

```
exclude = ('user',)
```

and at `save_model`

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Check docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model)

If you want to add this to normal views

#### forms.py

```
class XXForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(XXForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def save(self, commit=True):
        obj = super(XXForm, self).save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.user
        if commit:
            obj.save()
        return obj
```

#### views.py

```
def xxview(request, *args, **kwargs): # your args 
    if request.POST:
        #your stuff
        form = XXForm(request.POST......., user=request.user)
    else:
        # your stuff
```

Check views [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/10/09/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-6.html)

Comment: This is for the admin site, but the question is for a regular view.

Comment: the same at your form
and for view just get the user from `request.user`

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, guys, but can i do something like that? ```id_user = models.OneToOneField(Account, default="{{ request.user }}", on_delete=models.CASCADE)```

Comment: No as I shared it with you .. assign the `id_user` with the form or the view

Comment: @A.Raouf
 I try to do this and the ```id_user``` takes none value




```def cadastro_curriculo(request):
    form = InsereDadosPessoais(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
            obj.id_user = request.user
            super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        form.save()
        return redirect("vagas")
    return render(request, "personal/curriculo.html", {'form': form})```

Comment: @GustavoLisi def save is at the form level not the view

Comment: @GustavoLisi check the answer now

Answer (score 1):

I think you are Brazilian too :) Welcome! [I learned this from this site.](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/current_user.html)

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import User


class PersonalData(models.Model):
    id_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=True, null=True, verbose_name="CPF")
    rg = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True, null=True, verbose_name="RG")
    idade = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    data_nascimento = models.DateField(verbose_name="Data de Nascimento", null=True)
    genero = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=GENERO, null=True)
    estado_civil = models.CharField(max_length=13, null=True, choices=ESTADO_CIVIL, verbose_name="Estado Civil")
    data_inscricao = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Data de Inscrição', auto_now_add=True)
    ultimo_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='ùltimo Login', auto_now_add=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return '{} {}'.format(id_user.first_name, id_user.last_name)

   def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not obj.id_user:
             # Only set added_by during the first save.
             obj.id_user = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

**admin.py**

```
from .models import PersonalData

class PersonalDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     readonly_fields = ('id_user',)


admin.site.register(PersonalData, PersonalDataAdmin)
```

Important notes:

You don't have to create a field that saves the full name, [Django itself can do it for you](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model).

If you are going to use Django-Admin you can work with permissions within it by own User models. [Click here and read a little about.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/)

I recommend you use the built-in User model, it would look like this. Feel free to access my profile and get my contact information, I would be happy to help you with your project!

Comment: Please, can we talk? I think you can help me

Answer (score 0):

I'd suppose you have to make `id_user` field a foreign key to `Account` identifier which you should add to your model. In your described scenario `id_user` will "use" `Account.username` which is not obligated to be unique among all the users registered in the system. So, I suggest you to create an `id` field for `Account` and utilize it as a numeral identifier for that model.

Also, if I do not mistake, Django has an intrinsic `User` model which is intended for usage in such cases. Of course, you can extend that model for adding specific attributes.